# Too many independent variables in ARDL?

Tags: time-series, ardl

I have eight independent variables, and also think of adding a ninth variable for time. Is this too much? Are there any consequences?

Annual data for nine years.

Comment: I don't think that this question contains enough information yet for you to get a helpful answer. Although I don't know much about time-series analysis, I understand that much depends on the nature of your data, how many time points that you have, and what the outcome variable is. Please edit the question to provide a more background.